# dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: raspberry-pi, kali-linux

I am trying to install Kali Linux full on my Raspberry Pi 3 with the command:

```
apt-get install kali-linux-full
```

I get the following error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

I then tried:

```
apt-get install exploitdb
```

but get the same error. How can I fix it?

**Notes:**

- Using a Raspberry Pi 3
- rom- nethunter->nexmon build to enable monitor mode on WiFi
- `apt-get purge exploitdb` gives:

  > Package 'exploitdb' is not installed, so not removed

[image]